# Can a puntured $\mathbb{C}P^2$ admit an affine structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is there an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ for $\mathbb{C}P^2 \setminus \{pt\}$ such that all transition maps of this atlas are affine maps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is 'no'.  I don't have access to the right references right now, but I think an argument goes as follows.  (Also, as Will points out below, you can use Stiefel-Whitney classes to get the same result.)

If there were such an atlas on $X^4 = \mathbb{CP}^2\setminus\{p\}$, then it would induce a torsion-free flat affine structure on $X^4$.  Since $X^4$ is simply connected, this affine structure would have a developing map $x:X^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ that would be an immersion.

In particular, it would follow that, for any embedded $2$-sphere $S^2\subset X^4$ that is smoothly homotopic through immersions to a standard linear $\mathbb{CP}^1\subset X^4=\mathbb{CP}^2\setminus\{p\}$, we would obtain an immersion $x:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^4$ whose (oriented) normal bundle would have Euler number $1$ (because two such $\mathbb{CP}^1$s intersect transversely at a single point).

By perturbing such an $S^2$ slightly in $X^4$, we can arrange that the immersion $x:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^4$ have only transverse self-intersections, with each self-intersection consisting of two points in the domain $S^2$.  However, by a theorem of Whitney (reference needed, maybe the paper of Chern and Spanier on oriented surfaces in 4-space is also relevant here), the Euler number of this normal bundle must be equal to the algebraic number of self-intersections (counted with signs) in the domain $S^2$, which is necessarily an *even* integer.

Since we have seen that the oriented normal bundle of this $S^2$ in $X^4$ has Euler number 1, this is impossible.

Comment: Isn't this Stiefel-Whitney classes? The fact that the map is an immersion implies the tangent bundle is trivial, and in particular the second Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes. But because the tangent bundle of $S^2$ has Euler number $2$, and thus trivial second class, and the normal bundle has Euler number $1$, and thus nontrivial second class, the tangent bundle has nontrivial second class.

Comment: @WillSawin:  Yes, of course, one can certainly do it that way.  Essentially, the theorem of Whitney follows the same way, but is more precise because it takes into account orientations and signs, and Whitney's theorem was the first thing that came to my mind, so that is what I used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  and your attention to my question.

Comment: I confess that I should make effort to understand the  answers of  You  and @Ben  But  I would like to thank both of you for  your  attention to my question.

Answer (score 3):

The punctured projective plane has no complex affine structure: it contains a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^1$, which would then develop into the model geometry, i.e. into affine space $\mathbb{C}^2$, contradicting the Liouville theorem on bounded holomorphic functions. I don't know about a real affine structure.

More generally, the Hartogs extension theorem prevents $\mathbb{CP}^n-K$ admitting a holomorphic affine connection, if $K$ is a compact subset of the domain of an affine chart $K \subset \mathbb{C}^n \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your attention to my question.